# $\int_U |f(z)| |dz|^2$ Is this complex or topology?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, complex-integration

[image]

I am totally clueless. Can anyone help me ?  What does that operator modulus and square means?

Comment: Which book is this from? Perhaps there is a part in the beginning of the book explaining different notations

Comment: It seems that $|dz|^2$ denotes the euclidean area element in the $z$-plane.

Answer (score 4):

$\partial U$ is the *boundary* of $U$, and $d(z, \partial U)$ denotes the *distance* from $z$ to the boundary of $U$:
$$
 d(z, \partial U) = \inf \{ |z - w| : w \in \partial U \} \, .
$$

If $0 \le \rho \le r < d(z, \partial U)$ then the disk $B(z, r)$ is contained in $U$, and an application of Cauchy's integral formula  gives
$$
 |f(z)| \le \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{0}^{2 \pi} |f(z + \rho e^{it}| dt \,.
$$
In other words: $|f|$ is *subharmonic,* so that its value at a point is $\le$ the average of the values in a circle around that point.

It follows (by integration with respect to $\rho \, d\rho$ over the interval $[0, r]$) that the value at a point is $\le$ the average of the values in a *disk* around that point, and that can be estimated above by the average value in $U$ (which is supposed to be finite):

$$
 |f(z)|  \le \frac{1}{\pi r^2} \int_{B_r(z)} |f(z)| |dz|^2 \le \frac{1}{\pi r^2} \int_{U} |f(z)| |dz|^2 \, .
$$

(As Christian Blatter said, $|dz|^2$ is used here as a notation for the area  element $dx \, dy$.)

Now take the limit  for $r \to d(z, \partial U)$.

Comment: +1 from me. I think the proof is neat.